# Take path from application root in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

```
function detailed_link(cell_rowid) {
        var $tabs = $('#infrTab').tabs();
        $tabs.tabs('select', 1); // switch to third tab~
        objRowData = $('#' + pageGridId).getRowData(cell_rowid);
        //document.getElementById("Name").value = objRowData.amount;

        loadPage('Infringement/TaskDetail', 'taskDetails'); /* Path */
    }
```

I have write a javascript function loadPage(), that needs a path to some page as a parameter. I need to give this path from the application root. I dont want a relative path. Please let me know how can I do it.

Comment: Instead of the absolute path.... i will recommend to use the context path, so if your page is in `http://www.so.com/pages/one.aspx` you will be using `/pages/one.aspx`

Comment: In this case if the javascript is present in some internal folders , I would have to change the path.

Comment: Do you have access to `Url.RouteUrl()`? (you'll get this in a .NET 4.0 asp.net app)

Comment: @Alastair can you please give me some reference.

Comment: @vaibhav when you use it from the root folder, it doesn't matter what directory you are located. From the root folder i mean as the example i gave to you `/pages/one.aspx`

Comment: @vaibhav: Is this a WebForms app? or a MVC app?

Comment: @vaibhav: Have a look at my answer:)

Answer (score 6):

I have this piece of Javascript in my Site.master, just underneath the jquery import and above any reference to my own scripts.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //Function that provides a relative URL for cases of virtual directories.
        jQuery.url = function (path) {
            return '<%: Url.Action("Index","Home") %>' + path;
        };
 </script>
```

This assumes that your '/' address is handled by your Index method in your Home controller (the standard).

You can then access it via:

```
$.url('Infringement/TaskDetail')
```

Comment: Do I have to write  jQuery.url = function (path) { 
            return '<%: Url.Action("Index","Home") %>' + path; 
        }; 
in my javascript file. Or it is internal to jquery.

Comment: I personally add it to the Site.Master before MY javascript file as I can then guarantee that it will run before it's ever used.

Comment: Its adding a new method to the jQuery object, much like an extension method in .NET

Comment: Great idea.  However, I'd change the code to something more like this since not everyone has a home index:  `return '<%: Url.Content("~") %>' + path;`

Comment: @mattmc3: That's a much cleaner version that mine :)

Answer (score 1):

suppose that you have a page with this address: `http://sub.domain.com/page.htm`. use the following in page code to achive those results:

- `window.location.host` : you'll get `sub.domain.com:8080` or `sub.domain.com:80`
- `window.location.hostname` : you'll get `sub.domain.com`
- `window.location.protocol` : you'll get `http:`
- `window.location.port` : you'll get `8080` or `80`
- `window.location.origin` : you'll get `http://sub.domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use relative path, because you never know where will be application root. If your application will be installed with another applications in IIS, then its root could be for example `http://www.domain.com/iis/youapp/pages/one.aspx`